# CSS Accordion using data from XML/XSLT Files

Tags: html, xml, css, xslt, data-binding

OK Here's the thing, i have this HTML/CSS File that has an Accordion style to it that we're using for a project.

I Need to pull data from an XML file that i am testing with XSLT

See code below :
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <Supplier>Empire Burlesque</Supplier>
        <Info>Some basic info on the Supplier </Info>
        <Email>email@mail.com </Email>
        <Phone>1-868-555-5555</Phone>
        <Image>http://scmedia.theknot.com/~/media/EDA74AC2F5C34074A02CA053E968547D.ashx</Image>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

Here is the XSLT code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>

  <body>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<div>
  <div style="height:auto;width:265px;"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"/>
  <div style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px"><div style="font-style: italic; color: #E50AC2; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);"><xsl:value-of select="Supplier"/></div></div>
<div style="float:left; padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;">
   <xsl:element name="img">
              <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="Image"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="align">left</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

</div>
  <div style="font-style: italic; color: #777; font-size: 12px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);"><xsl:value-of select="Info"/></div>
</div>
<div style="font-style: italic; color: #777; font-size: 12px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);"><xsl:value-of select="Email"/> | <xsl:value-of select="Phone"/></div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to use this Accordion : http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Accordion/
I already have an edited version of this file above with my own styles, i just need to know how i can use the Accordion Html/CSS file and pull data from an XML file

Thanks Much

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Copy the accordion HTML
- Include the accordion CSS in a `link` tag
- Wrap in the [simplified syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#result-element-stylesheet)
- Use `xsl:for-each` to create the list

For example:

```
<html xsl:version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
  <head>
    <title>Expense Report Summary</title>
    <link href="foo.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Total Amount: <xsl:value-of select="expense-report/total"/></p>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*">
      <!--...-->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```